# Subscript out of range in VBA when running this code

Tags: excel, vba

When i initially run the code below in debug mode, there is no problems. However when i stop and rerun it again, it says Subscript out of range. Why is that so? Not sure why such error is popping out.

```
Dim date1 As Double
strDate1 = Sheets("Part2").Cells(i, 1).Value
matchEndRow = Application.Match(CDbl(strDate1), Sheets("1.A").Range("A:A"), 1)
MsgBox matchEndRow
matchEndRow = matchEndRow - 1
MsgBox matchEndRow
```

Need some guidance.

Comment: Where do you define `i`?

Comment: outside of this.. For i=3 to 4.. Next and this code is inside..

Comment: it says `Subscript out of range` or `Type missmatch`?

Comment: Subscript out of range

Comment: Which line is it failing on?

Comment: do you have any other workbooks opened when code runs? If yes, try to change `Sheets("Part2")` and `Sheets("1.A")` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part2")` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1.A")`

Comment: @simoco thanks u solved it.. I had another workbook open.. anyway will change it to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, there was another workbook opened when code runs.

So changing

`Sheets("Part2")` and `Sheets("1.A")`

to

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part2")` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1.A")` solves the problem.